# Python (Pygame) - Object instances moving at different speed to background

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

This has been doing my head in for days. I'm trying to create a game with a player fixed in the middle, and a tile-based background that moves fluidly behind the player and generates additional tile images as the player moves. The background works perfectly thus far.

The issue arises when I try to add objects to the background (e.g. a tree). I want this object to stay fixed to a certain background location, but as the player moves, the object gradually moves in relation to the background. That is, the object will move as the player moves (as it should), but it will move *too* much.

I've isolated the cause to the World.update method, the self.tileShift section. If you remove this entire if/elif section, the behaviour looks good (except of course the background doesn't update properly, so we need this section). Somehow, as the tileShift skips over, every object on the screen will skip by a few pixels too. After spending over a week of research and experimenting, I still can't manage to fix it. I've tried changing the image, changing the tileShift cutoff point, changing the order of calling update/draw methods, etc.

Refer to (massively stripped down from the original, but self-contained) code below. Note that we need a background tile image with patterns on it (see World class init), otherwise you won't be able to see the behaviour I'm describing as the erroneous movement is so gradual. For best performance, use a 70x70 png image.

Hopefully this explanation makes sense, please let me know if any additional info is required. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
import pygame

# Initialisation
SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT = 800, 850
pygame.init() # Initialise pygame
window = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)) # Set the window surface (the main screen of the game)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game") # Game window caption
window_rect = window.get_rect()

# GLOBAL VARIABLES
WorldMove = dict(x=0, y=0) # List for the direction and amount the background moves as the player moves
PlayerMoveSpeed = 5

# CLASSES
class World(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tileShift = dict(x=0, y=0)  # Tracker for when the player has passed from one map tile to another

        # Load and set up the tile images
        self.tiles = pygame.image.load("Images\Tiles\Tile.png")
        self.tileSize = self.tiles.get_rect().size[0] # Assumes a square size
        self.map = pygame.Surface((self.tileSize*14,self.tileSize*15)) # Visible area surface size, based on tile size
        self.rect = self.map.get_rect() # Create a rect attribute for the World, so it can be blitted to the window
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = -self.tileSize,-self.tileSize # The map is blitted starting one tile size above left of the screen (so we see no whitespace)

    def update(self):
        # Move the map around the player based on WorldMove, which is set in the player_move function
        self.rect.x += WorldMove["x"]
        self.rect.y += WorldMove["y"]

        # Update the tileShift based on player movement so we know when they've moved onto another tile
        if WorldMove["x"] != 0: self.tileShift["x"] -= WorldMove["x"]
        if WorldMove["y"] != 0: self.tileShift["y"] -= WorldMove["y"]

        # Once the self.tileShift has passed the size of one of the tile images, reset it and move self.matrix by 1
        if self.tileShift["x"] < -self.tileSize:
            self.tileShift["x"] = 0 # Reset the tileShift variable
            self.rect.x = -self.tileSize # Reset the point from which the map is blitted to window to top left of visible screen
        elif self.tileShift["x"] > self.tileSize:
            self.tileShift["x"] = 0
            self.rect.x = -self.tileSize
        if self.tileShift["y"] > self.tileSize:
            self.tileShift["y"] = 0
            self.rect.y = -self.tileSize
        elif self.tileShift["y"] < -self.tileSize:
            self.tileShift["y"] = 0
            self.rect.y = -self.tileSize

    def draw(self):
        # Draw the tiles in a grid in the visible area
        for y in range(15): # Visible number of tiles on y axis
            for x in range(14): # Visible number of tiles on x axis
                self.map.blit(self.tiles, (self.tileSize*x, self.tileSize*y)) # Blit each tile onto self.map
        window.blit(self.map, self.rect) # Blit self.map onto the window

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((35, 35))
        self.image.fill((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2) # Player is always in middle of screen

    def player_move(self):
        global WorldMove # Make sure that we're referring to and updating the global variable for the world movement

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        x, y = 0, 0

        if key[pygame.K_w] or key[pygame.K_UP]: y = PlayerMoveSpeed
        if key[pygame.K_d] or key[pygame.K_RIGHT]: x = -PlayerMoveSpeed
        if key[pygame.K_a] or key[pygame.K_LEFT]: x = PlayerMoveSpeed
        if key[pygame.K_s] or key[pygame.K_DOWN]: y = -PlayerMoveSpeed

        if x != 0 and y != 0: # If more than one key pressed, move diagonally
            WorldMove["x"] = int(x / 1.5)
            WorldMove["y"] = int(y / 1.5)
        else:
            WorldMove["x"] = x
            WorldMove["y"] = y

    def draw(self):
        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)

class Object(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,100))
        self.image.fill((50,50,250))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = window_rect.center
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = 100, 100 # Spawn location of the object

    def update(self): # Move the object as the world moves around the player
        self.rect.x += WorldMove["x"]
        self.rect.y += WorldMove["y"]

    def draw(self): # Blit the object onto the screen at its location
        window.blit(self.image, self.rect)

# Set Objects
world = World()
object = Object()
player = Player()

# Main Loop
gameRunning = True

while gameRunning:

    # Player events
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            gameRunning = False

        player.player_move() # Move player based on movement key(s) pressed (if any)

    # Class updates and drawing to the screen
    window.fill((255, 255, 255)) # Fill the window with background white
    world.update()
    world.draw()
    object.update()
    object.draw()
    player.draw()

    pygame.display.update() # Refresh the display

# End - only reaches this point if gameRunning = False
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: In case it helps you do more research, this is called *parallax* scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the `self.rect` of the `World` instance to `-self.tileSize`, in- or decrement the rect attributes and the `self.tileShift` by the `self.tileSize`:

```
if self.tileShift["x"] < -self.tileSize:
    self.tileShift["x"] += self.tileSize
    self.rect.x -= self.tileSize
elif self.tileShift["x"] > self.tileSize:
    self.tileShift["x"] -= self.tileSize
    self.rect.x += self.tileSize
if self.tileShift["y"] > self.tileSize:
    self.tileShift["y"] -= self.tileSize
    self.rect.y += self.tileSize
elif self.tileShift["y"] < -self.tileSize:
    self.tileShift["y"] += self.tileSize
    self.rect.y -= self.tileSize
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you very much